# Using the assigned name of a field with 'AS' within a JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, coalesce

I have this code..

```
SELECT u.*, COALESCE(c2.name,u.state) AS real_state, c.name AS real_country, bc.alpha3 AS country_iso FROM gimko_v2.users AS u
        INNER JOIN gimko_v2.countries AS c ON u.country=c.id 
        LEFT JOIN gimko_v2.countries AS c2 ON u.state=c2.id 
        LEFT JOIN gimko_blesta.countries AS bc ON c.country_iso_code=bc.alpha2
        LEFT JOIN gimko_blesta.states AS bs ON bc.alpha2=bs.country_alpha2 AND real_state=bs.name
        WHERE u.blesta_id=0;
```

The problem likes in this area:

```
COALESCE(c2.name,u.state) AS real_state
```

and

```
LEFT JOIN gimko_blesta.states AS bs ON bc.alpha2=bs.country_alpha2 AND real_state=bs.name
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'real_state' in 'on clause'
```

How can I use the result of `COALESCE(c2.name,u.state)` in a `JOIN`?

Thanks!

Comment: By using the expression instead of the alias.  The `from` clause is evaluated before the `select`, so it doesn't know about aliases defined in the `select`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `gimko_blesta.states` even need to be in the source tables? None of its columns are in the select list/criteria, and it's joined in with a LEFT JOIN, so doesn't seem like it's necessary.

In any case, you would need to make it a derived table first, and join gimko_blesta.states to the derived table, or just use the expression in the JOIN, like `COALESCE(c2.name,u.state) = bs.name`, below:

```
SELECT u.*, COALESCE(c2.name,u.state) AS real_state, c.name AS real_country, bc.alpha3 AS country_iso 
FROM gimko_v2.users AS u
        INNER JOIN gimko_v2.countries AS c ON u.country=c.id 
        LEFT JOIN gimko_v2.countries AS c2 ON u.state=c2.id 
        LEFT JOIN gimko_blesta.countries AS bc ON c.country_iso_code=bc.alpha2
        LEFT JOIN gimko_blesta.states AS bs ON bc.alpha2=bs.country_alpha2 AND COALESCE(c2.name,u.state) = bs.name
        WHERE u.blesta_id=0;
```

Comment: Yes it's needed, I added a column for it in the select list after I posted this question. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use virtual aliases at the same level of your query you may have to repeat the whole expression or use a sub select to access in your parent query

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT u.*, 
COALESCE(c2.name,u.state) AS real_state,
c.name AS real_country,
bc.alpha3 AS country_iso ,
bc.alpha2
FROM gimko_v2.users AS u
        INNER JOIN gimko_v2.countries AS c ON u.country=c.id 
        LEFT JOIN gimko_v2.countries AS c2 ON u.state=c2.id 
        LEFT JOIN gimko_blesta.countries AS bc ON c.country_iso_code=bc.alpha2
) t
LEFT JOIN gimko_blesta.states AS bs ON t.alpha2=bs.country_alpha2 AND t.real_state=bs.name
WHERE t.blesta_id=0;
```

Also in sub-select you have to select all the needed columns that will be used in outer join for parent query like in your case i have selected `bc.alpha2` in inner query because to join with `states` this column is needed